# How to render data in react getting undefined state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching data inside componentDidMount but i get undefined during initial render and again render happens and during that time the state variable gets populated. Now when it is not undefined and after population I want to destructure it and display the data inside my component.

Note: getProjectDetails() makes a GET req to populate the data.

I am getting typer error name of undefined.

```
  constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
               projectDetails: ''
            };
        }

    componentDidMount() {
            getProjectDetails(this.props.logged_in_user, this.props.projectId)
                .then( res => {
                    this.setState({projectDetails: res});
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error: ' + err);
                })
        }

    //Inside render()

    render() {
            console.log('Project details from API endpoint: ', this.state.projectDetails.project)

            const { projectDetails } = this.state;
            console.log('Destructure: ', projectDetails);

            const project = this.state.projectDetails.project;

    let {  
                name,
                location,
                city,
                builder_name } = project;
```

Comment: You might try to set the Async function call in a componentWillMount method, that might be better.

Comment: I used componentWillMount but still getting same error

Comment: Your initial state does not have the object project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check with the following if the state is set:

```
render() {
    if(this.state.projectDetails === ''){
        return <div>Loading</div>;
    }
    else{
        return <div>{this.state.projectDetails.project}</div>
    }
}
```

So as long as the state is false, Loading will be returned, if there is a value, then `this.state.projectDetails.project` gets returned. I hope that helps.

**Edit:**
The render method will be called twice, before the data is fetched and then, after the state is set. So this would only return the data, if its really set.

Comment: Your answer works thanks man. I want to ask you while dealing with undefined state for initial render I should always add if statement saying loading if I don;t do that then I get type error

Comment: any other way to handle this undefined state situation ? or this is the best case ?

Comment: At your point, I just would make your initial state not to `''`. I would make it to undefined or null, so you could just make `if(!this.state.projectDetails)`.