# How to pass props as object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the user data from an api using the fetch() function. In the render function I want to pass the props using the ...userdata but it gives me error when I create object before return statement. The error is :
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

Error is because at the time of loading the application there is no userData, its fetched only on search button click.

Please let me know how can I create the object and pass it as prop, instead of passing each member of object separately as prop. i.e.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SearchBar from "./components/search";
import Result from "./components/result";

class ContactSearch extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      // userData: {
        // id: 0,
        // name: "",
        // username: ""
      // },
      userData : [],
      userAddr : {},
      searchDone: false,
      errorMessage: ""
    };

    this.callUserData = this.callUserData.bind(this);
  }

  callUserData(user) {
    const url = `<URL>`;

    fetch(url)
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        var { ...addr} = data[0].address;
        this.setState({
          userData: [...data],
          userAddr: addr,
          searchDone: true,
          errorMessage: ""
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // If an error is catch, it's sent to SearchBar as props
        this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });
      });

    function handleErrors(response) {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
      }
      return response;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { searchDone, userData, userAddr, errorMessage } = this.state;
    console.log('Inside render');

        let **user** = {
                id : userData[0].id,
                name:userData[0].name,
                email:userData[0].email,
                address:userAddr
            };

        return (
          <div className="ContactSearch">
            <SearchBar
              callBackFromParent={this.callUserData}
              error={errorMessage}
            />

            {searchDone && userData && (
              <Result

                    {...**user**}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        );
  }
}

export default ContactSearch;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: The problem is that `userData[0]` is `undefined` while the `fetch` is ongoing. You need to account for that in the render logic.

Comment: Do you need something like this` <Result user={ props} />`?

Comment: @Alex, you are correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render data in react getting undefined state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204066/how-to-render-data-in-react-getting-undefined-state)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement to check whether or not the data you need was loaded into the state already, so as to avoid trying to access it on the first render:

```
const { searchDone, userData, userAddr, errorMessage } = this.state;
let user = null;
if (userData.length > 0) {
    user = {
        id : userData[0].id,
        name:userData[0].name,
        email:userData[0].email,
        address:userAddr
    };
}
```

A shorter way to do the same thing:

```
const { searchDone, userData, userAddr, errorMessage } = this.state;
let user = searchDone && {
    id : userData[0].id,
    name:userData[0].name,
    email:userData[0].email,
    address:userAddr
};
```

Comment: your first solution gives same error again.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

userData is not null but just an empty array.

Second one works fine.
Thanks.

Comment: You're right, I missed that you're initializing `userData` as an empty array, sorry! I've edited my answer

Comment: I did the same   :-)
i.e. if (userData.length > 0) .....

Thanks.

Comment: That's great to hear, you're welcome, @Mahesh! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider upvoting it and accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this

```
<Result user={searchDone && userData[0]} />
```

Result component could be like this

```
const Result=(props)=>
 ( props.user?<div>{props.user.id}</div>:'no result..^.^')
```

if your data is like
[{id:1},{id:2}]
remove extra Bracket from data `userData: [data]`

should be like below

```
      userData: data,
```

[temporary sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-pass-props-as-object-4nf67)